# flot charts - externally selecting bars

Tags: jquery, graph, charts, flot

I'm using flot http://code.google.com/p/flot/ and would like to highlight a particular bar in the series when the user hovers over a link, does anyone know how to do that?

Cheers,

Tim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing you're looking for is `highlight`, which is documented in the [API.txt](http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt):

> ```
> highlight(series, datapoint)
>
> Highlight a specific datapoint in the data series. You can either
> specify the actual objects, e.g. if you got them from a
> "plotclick" event, or you can specify the indices, e.g.
> highlight(1, 3) to highlight the fourth point in the second series
> (remember, zero-based indexing).
> ```

So your code would look something like this:

```
//before this, $.plot has been called and assigned to "plot"
$('#mylink').mouseover(function(){
   plot.highlight(1,3);
}).mouseout(function(){
   plot.unhighlight(1,3);
});
```

Comment: how can i get the data.label value of highlighted area?

Comment: could it update the chart without reload the page? for example there's a button to update the chart data.

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi - It sure could - check out the graph on the front page of the [flot website](http://www.flotcharts.org/).