# Highlight and unhiglight jquery flot pie chart

Tags: html, canvas, charts, flot

I'm using version 1.1 of jquery flot pie charts. I was successful in drawing a pie chart with this plugin.

I've a requirement to programatically highlight some sectors of pie chart based on some conditions.

I googled about this and noticed that highlight and unhighlight APIs for Pie charts was not exposed before v0.9 and it has been made available after that.

However it is not happening for me yet. It would be helpful, if someone can share a snippet which emphasizes on how to programatically highlight a sector of Pie flot chart.

Answer (score 0):

The Flot pie chart plugin does not expose an API for this. Here a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jbwkmvb/) implementing the workaround form [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16474368/2610249) to get it to work. This then allows for calls like this to highlight the number-th series:

```
plot.highlight(plot.getData()[number - 1]);
```